# IE7 and IE 8 Youtube embedded video Error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, youtube, internet-explorer-7, embed

Embedded YouTube video is giving Javascript error in IE7 and IE8. Please see the error message below:

[image]

I could not find much help on iternet about this error.

I have used following code on my web page to embed the video:

```
<iframe class="you" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/5TZHYT6x7zc?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" wmode="Opaque"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the result of a configuration change for the compatibility mode of IE 8.  If you are on a network and your browser configuration is set by a network admin, they may have pushed this change without your knowledge.  Most likely, others outside of your network that still use IE8 will not experience this problem.

You can get the video to run with the IE Dev Tools and forcing the page into “IE 8 Standards” document mode.  However, if you want this to work throughout your network, you'd have to talk to your server admin.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the old embed style in youtube:

```
<object width="560" height="315"><param name="movie"     value="http://www.youtube.com/v/nuTQq0dXm-M?hl=fr_FR&amp;version=3"></param><param     name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/nuTQq0dXm-M?hl=fr_FR&amp;version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
```

Comment: I want to avoid using old method. Is there any other solutions?